# How and where can I propose new MTG cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Where - if anywhere - can I go to put forward a proposal of a new card in magic the gathering?

I figured that the cards must go through a process before being released. I was wondering if I could get my ideas onto the process chain. Can I contact anyone to do this?

Looking on the Magic wizards site, I kinda got lost in the FAQs looking for this and run up a blank.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wizards of the Coast employees are not allowed to look at unsolicited card designs, from the [Wizards of the Coast FAQ on Idea Submissions](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2236):

> **Game Submissions**
>
> We do not review unsolicited game or card submissions, return submissions, or make comments on submissions we haven't reviewed.

If you want other people to look at and critique your designs you can go to places like [MTG Salvation's Custom Card Creation forum](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/custom-card-creation), but the only way to make actual cards is to work for Wizards or submit your design for something like [You Make the Card](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/You_Make_the_Card)

Comment: As a side note, a common reason that companies don't accept unsolicited creative contributions is to avoid copyright violation lawsuits. If you design a card, you own the copyright, and without a contest like *You Make the Card*, the copyright does not transfer to Wizards when you send it to them. That makes for a sticky legal situation if they make it a real card without getting a license from you.

Comment: Another place to go for letting custom card get reviewed is the [custommagic subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/custommagic). I personally like the community there very much.

Answer (score 4):

The only real way this could have been done was by winning the Magic Invitational Tournament but alas that no longer exists.

> The Magic Invitational Tournament, formerly called the Duelist
>   Invitational, is a tournament in which successful pro-players are
>   gathered by Wizards of the Coasts to play round-robin in various
>   formats, often joke formats or very unusual formats. During the
>   tournament, the players submit card ideas. The winner of the
>   tournament will get to design a card to see print in a future set, of
>   course after R&D had it's input on the card. However, the card to see
>   print is not necessarily the same card as submitted in the tournament
>   and sometimes not even remotely related to it.

[SOURCE](http://mtg.wikia.com/wiki/Invitational_Cards)

Comment: The other answer mentions You Make the Card as another way community members have created cards.